# CD/DVD directory cataloguing application for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd, cd

Does anyone know a good application for cataloguing directories on Ubuntu that supports ext4, etc. and NTFS and FAT32?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you ask for, but is `tree` what you're looking for?
http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree